# MySQL slow queries with rows sent/examined equal to 0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a Rails (v.2.3.8) application with a MySQL database. In the slow query log on the database server, there are a large number of entries such as:

```
# Query_time: 3.471884  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use prod;
SET timestamp=1312909843;
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE (`pages`.`controller` = 'forum_categories' AND `pages`.`action` = 'show')  LIMIT 1;
```

Note that the query time is 3.47 seconds, while the number of rows sent and examined are both 0. When I run this same query using the MySQL client (both on the MySQL server and on the application server), I get a result in less than 100ms. All necessary table fields are indexed and there are only 70 records in the table. Any idea why these long-running, seemingly useless queries would be running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Here’s an example from a slow query log:
>
> ```
> 1 # Time: 030303 0:51:27
> 2 # User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
> 3 # Query_time: 25 Lock_time: 0 Rows_sent: 3949 Rows_examined: 378036
> 4 SELECT ...
> ```
>
> Line 1 shows when the query was logged, and line 2 shows who executed
>   it. Line 3 shows how many seconds it took to execute, how long it
>   waited for table locks at the MySQL server level **(not at the storage
>   engine level)**, ...
>
> Be careful not to read too much into the slow query log. If you see
>   the same query in the log many times, there’s a good chance that it’s
>   slow and needs optimization. But just because a query appears in the
>   log doesn’t mean it’s a bad query, or even necessarily a slow one.
>   **You may find a slow query, run it yourself, and find that it executes in a fraction of a second.** Appearing in the log simply means the
>   query took a long time then; it doesn’t mean it will take a long time
>   now or in the future. There are many reasons why a query can be slow
>   sometimes and fast at other times:
>   • A table may have been locked,
>   causing the query to wait. The Lock_time indi- cates how long the
>   query waited for locks to be released.
>   • The data or indexes may not
>   have been cached in memory yet. This is common when MySQL is first
>   started or hasn’t been well tuned.
>   • A nightly backup process may have
>   been running, making all disk I/O slower.
>   • The server may have been
>   running other queries at the same time, slowing down this query.
>   As a
>   result, you should view the slow query log as only a partial record of
>   what’s happened. You can use it to generate a list of possible
>   suspects, but you need to investigate each of them in more depth.

The data were quoted from the book:
“High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, Replication, and More, Second Edition, by Baron Schwartz et al.
Copyright 2008 O’Reilly Media, Inc., 9780596101718.”

Comment: Do other queries run quickly?  This could be a system resources issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have index key on column `pages.controller` and `pages.action`?

The table might have a lot of entries, and thus query needs 3.47 secs to look for the correct row one by one if you don't implement index key.